# Using Redisson(V3.23.5) occurs a warning exception

Tags: dns, netty, redisson

Dependencies:

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.redisson</groupId>
            <artifactId>redisson-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.23.5</version>
        </dependency>
```

**System Environment:** macos big sur Version 11.1; jdk1.8.0_151

Start up redisson client after a minutes, console print exception like below:

```
10:41:07.232 [redisson-netty-5-2] WARN io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsNameResolver - Unexpected exception: UDP [[id: 0xb15b2bf9]]
io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: readerIndex(0) + length(2) exceeds writerIndex(0): PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf(ridx: 0, widx: 0, cap: 4096)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:98)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioMessageChannel$NioMessageUnsafe.read(AbstractNioMessageChannel.java:93)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:714)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: readerIndex(0) + length(2) exceeds writerIndex(0): PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf(ridx: 0, widx: 0, cap: 4096)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.checkReadableBytes0(AbstractByteBuf.java:1477)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.readShort(AbstractByteBuf.java:750)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.readUnsignedShort(AbstractByteBuf.java:766)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.dns.DnsResponseDecoder.decode(DnsResponseDecoder.java:37)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.dns.DatagramDnsResponseDecoder.decodeResponse(DatagramDnsResponseDecoder.java:62)
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsNameResolver$1.decodeResponse(DnsNameResolver.java:198)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.dns.DatagramDnsResponseDecoder.decode(DatagramDnsResponseDecoder.java:58)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.dns.DatagramDnsResponseDecoder.decode(DatagramDnsResponseDecoder.java:30)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:88)
    ... 16 common frames omitted
```

This exception does not affect the normal running.

How to resolve this exception?